# How to change the names of columns in multiple dataframes in a list based on conditions?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list `all_input` that contains 13 dataframes. These dfs have different numbers of columns, sometimes with different column headers. There are 6 columns present in every df that I need, and I need them to all have the same names, shown here

```
 header_cols <- c( "tribal_name", "st_usps_cd", "scc", "description", "total_emissions", "uom" )
```

Some dfs already have the correct names, some do not. Some have a few columns with the correct names, but the rest not. For example, one df may have "pollutant_desc" for a column I need to be called "description", while another may have "pollutant".

Is there a way I can change this? My plan was to make a mapping file that would have one column with the current column names, and one column with the target column names such as:

```
current                target
pollutant_desc         description
pollutant              description
tribe                  tribal_name  
tribes                 tribal_name
tribe_name             tribal_name
```

etc. This may be problematic though, as more dfs are added in the future they could have names not present in the mapping file. I considered using an ifelse statement like this:

```
if ( "pollutant_desc" %in% colnames() ) {
      rename( description = pollutant_desc )
    }
```

but am unsure how to format that for multiple dataframes in a list, and also when there are multiple different header names. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the 6 columns that you want are present in all the dataframes, the lookup approach sounds good to me.

Here is an example to do it with 4 columns.

Creating a lookup table and some fake data

```
lookup_table <- data.frame(orignal_col = c('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'), 
                 new_col = c( "tribal_name", "st_usps_cd", "scc", "description"))

df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:3, col1 = 1:3, col2 = 3:5, col3 = 4:6, col4 = 2:4)
df2 <- data.frame(a = 1:3, col1 = 1:3, b = 1:3,col2 = 3:5, col3 = 4:6, col4 = 2:4)
all_input <- list(df1, df2)

all_input
#[[1]]
#  a col1 col2 col3 col4
#1 1    1    3    4    2
#2 2    2    4    5    3
#3 3    3    5    6    4

#[[2]]
#  a col1 b col2 col3 col4
#1 1    1 1    3    4    2
#2 2    2 2    4    5    3
#3 3    3 3    5    6    4
```

We can use `lapply` on the list and use `match` to replace column names.

```
lapply(all_input, function(x) {
   names(x)[match(lookup_table$orignal_col, names(x))] <- lookup_table$new_col
   x
})

#[[1]]
#  a tribal_name st_usps_cd scc description
#1 1           1          3   4           2
#2 2           2          4   5           3
#3 3           3          5   6           4

#[[2]]
#  a tribal_name b st_usps_cd scc description
#1 1           1 1          3   4           2
#2 2           2 2          4   5           3
#3 3           3 3          5   6           4
```

Notice how both the dataframes have some additional columns other than those common 4 columns but the name changes only for 4 columns and rest of them remain unchanged.

Comment: Great answer.  I'll just add this requires exactly 1 match from each element in `lookup_table$orignal_col` in the column names for a given data frame to work correctly, so if that condition isn't satisfied then a slightly modified answer will be required.

Comment: This *almost* works!  When I do this, it renames the column to "1" instead of the name I set in the ```lookup_table$new_col```

Comment: Actually, when I use your example dataframes it does the same thing. Instead of replacing the matching columns with the new names, it replaces them with numbers. Suggestions to fix this?

Comment: @MarideeWeber If you don't have R4.0.0 you need to add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `data.frame` call of `lookup_table`. Try with `lookup_table <- data.frame(orignal_col = c('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'), new_col = c( "tribal_name", "st_usps_cd", "scc", "description"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you so much! I am using R 3.5.2, this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple approach:

```
data(mtcars)
df1 <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 4)
df2 <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 6)
df3 <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 8)
list <- list(df1, df2, df3)

list_names <- c("df1", "df2", "df3")
df_col_names <- paste0("col", 1:11)

names(list) <- list_names
list <- lapply(list, setNames, df_col_names)
```

You can obtain the `df_col_names` from a mapping table. if your new column names are consistent you may not need the mapping table. if they are not, you to do the lookup. `match` or a `left_join` will be useful in that case.